# Communicating between a parent and child in the React Native tree without access to parent's parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I'm trying to make a Radio Group from scratch for a customer (thus, I don't have access to the component they us it in). I have a RadioGroup component and a RadioOption component. From a customer's usage perspective, it would look like this:

```
class customerComponent(props..) {
  render() {
    <View>
      <RadioGroup {props..}>
        <RadioOption {props} />
        <RadioOption {props} />
        <RadioOption {props} />
      </RadioGroup>
    </View>
  }
}
```

How would I communicate between the two components? Without access to the component their being called from? For example, if a user selects a new option, how would I tell the RadioGroup?

Comment: One of the props you pass to the RadioOption is a function bound to the RadioGroup.  When you click on the RadioOption, it calls that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the selected option as a state value in the parent component like this:

```
class CustomerComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: 0,
  };

  handleOptionClick = (option) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: option });
  }

  render() {
    <View>
      <RadioGroup {props..} selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}>
        <RadioOption onClick={this.handleOptionClick} {props} />
        <RadioOption onClick={this.handleOptionClick} {props} />
        <RadioOption onClick={this.handleOptionClick} {props} />
      </RadioGroup>
    </View>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The higher order component would need to provide the options, as well as the callback to be ran when a selection is made. Here is a snack example of a simple radio group that may help you get started https://snack.expo.io/HJA88p3bL

And the code for that snack

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: []
  }

  onSelect = (x) => {
    this.setState({ 
      selected: this.state.selected.includes(x) 
      ? [ 
        ...this.state.selected.slice(0, this.state.selected.indexOf(x)),
        ...this.state.selected.slice(this.state.selected.indexOf(x) + 1)
        ]
      : [...this.state.selected, x]})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RadioGroup options={["One", "Two", "Three"]} selected={this.state.selected} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <View>
      {this.props.options.map(x => 
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => this.props.onSelect(x)}>
        <Text>{x}</Text> 
        <Text>{this.props.selected.includes(x) ? "X" : "O"}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>)}
    </View>
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```